# installation of cx_oracle fails

Tags: macos, cx-oracle

I am trying to install cx_Oracle on my Mac Mavericks. Met with the following error. Any help, please.

The sequence is:

```
sudo easy_install cx_Oracle
...
Processing cx_Oracle-5.1.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-eFOU_a/cx_Oracle-5.1.2/setup.cfg
Running cx_Oracle-5.1.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-eFOU_a/cx_Oracle-5.1.2/egg-dist-tmp-g2eCKt
ld: file not found: crt3.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not dig deeply but I found some workaround for this issue.
I cloned repo from https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle and ran

```
python setup.py build
```

Got an error:

```
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -L/opt/instantclient_11_2 -lclntsh -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so -shared-libgcc
ld: file not found: crt3.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

After that I just copy & paste the command from output

```
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -L/opt/instantclient_11_2 -lclntsh -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so -shared-libgcc
```

And ran

```
python setup.py install
```

SUDDENLY egg has been successfully installed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. First  download oracle mac client files from Oracle site, the two below

> Instant Client Package - Basic:  All files required to run OCI, OCCI
>
> Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus: Additional libraries and executable
>   for running SQL*Plus with Instant Client

2. Then unzip all and put in single folder.
   Now point that path to "LD LIBRARY PATH" for mac as two environment variable exports shown below

> export
>   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/myUserName/Desktop/ORA_CLIENT/oracle_client
>   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /Users/myUserName/Desktop/ORA_CLIENT/oracle_client

3. Now download cx_oracle source code tar ball, unzip it go to the source folder, run

> pip setup.py install

4. Will get the below error

> ld: file not found: crt3.o

5. Now copy the gcc bundle command just above the command line run output (sample pasted below)

> gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup
>   build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o
>   -L/Users/myUserName/Desktop/ORA_CLIENT/oracle_client -lclntsh -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so -shared-libgcc

6. Paste it in command line, hit enter. It will go thru. Now run “python setup.py install”. It will be done